# send data from javascript to django without sending request, post, get

Tags: javascript, django

I have a project is about web game, if the player end the game

```
#e.g.
bool state == false
```

then it will send the score back to the django backend, but i don't want the player have to press the submit button, is there any ways to do that?

i have no any complete idea, i just found some solution is about ajax, fetch api..., but i don't really know if those work or not.

my post can't pass the quality standard, is that means my post's word too less?